# Measure elapsed time between two events in fluentd

Tags: merge, duration, fluentd, elapsed

Im looking for a way to measure the elapsed time between to events using fluentd. Also it would be awesome to be able to merge two or more events.

Until now I was using logstash. There are two plugins for my usecase in logstash:

- [elapsed](http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/elapsed) and merge.

I just can't figure out how to do this in fluentd. What am I missing here ?

Example:

I have a text file containing process logs which looks like this:

```
Fri May  8 05:00:00 GMT 2015: start subprocess 1 with param p
Fri May  8 05:10:42 GMT 2015: some other message
Fri May  8 05:11:44 GMT 2015: doing more stuff
Fri May  8 05:10:00 GMT 2015: end subprocess 1
```

My goal is to measure the time it took to finish **subprocess 1** based on the event's timestamps. This can easily be done using the elapsed filter in logstash but I have no clue how to solve this in fluentd.

I want a :

```
2015-05-08 05:10:00 parsed: {"message":"end subprocess 1","elapsed.time":"10.0"}
```

.. or even better I want to merge some of fields of the events (e.g. the param from the start event):

```
2015-05-08 05:10:00 parsed: {"message":"end subprocess 1","elapsed.time":"10.0", "param": "p"}
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Your question might be too broad here.